# What is the difference between operator "=" and "==" in Bash?

Tags: bash, operators

It seems that these two operators are pretty much the same - is there a difference? When should I use `=` and when `==`?

Answer (score 85, accepted):

You must use `==` in numeric comparisons in `(( ... ))`:

```
$ if (( 3 == 3 )); then echo "yes"; fi
yes
$ if (( 3 = 3 ));  then echo "yes"; fi
bash: ((: 3 = 3 : attempted assignment to non-variable (error token is "= 3 ")
```

You may use either for string comparisons in `[[ ... ]]` or `[ ... ]` or `test`:

```
$ if [[ 3 == 3 ]]; then echo "yes"; fi
yes
$ if [[ 3 = 3 ]]; then echo "yes"; fi
yes
$ if [ 3 == 3 ]; then echo "yes"; fi
yes
$ if [ 3 = 3 ]; then echo "yes"; fi
yes
$ if test 3 == 3; then echo "yes"; fi
yes
$ if test 3 = 3; then echo "yes"; fi
yes
```

"String comparisons?", you say?

```
$ if [[ 10 < 2 ]]; then echo "yes"; fi    # string comparison
yes
$ if (( 10 < 2 )); then echo "yes"; else echo "no"; fi    # numeric comparison
no
$ if [[ 10 -lt 2 ]]; then echo "yes"; else echo "no"; fi  # numeric comparison
no
```

Comment: You should not use `==` with `[` or `test`, though. `==` is not part of the POSIX specification, and will not work with all shells (`dash`, in particular, does not recognize it).

Comment: @chepner: That's true, but the question is specifically about Bash.

Answer (score 30):

There's a subtle difference with regards to POSIX. Excerpt from the [Bash reference](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Conditional-Expressions.html):

> `string1 == string2`
>   True if the strings are equal.  `=` may be used in place of `==` for strict POSIX compliance.

Comment: No difference in bash though? Just a portability issue?