# bash string equality

Tags: bash, equals, equality

In `bash`, what's the difference, if any, between the equal and double equal test operators?

```
[[ "a" = "a" ]] && echo equal || echo not-equal
[[ "a" == "a" ]] && echo equal || echo not-equal
[[ "a" = "b" ]] && echo equal || echo not-equal
[[ "a" == "b" ]] && echo equal || echo not-equal
```

results in:

```
equal
equal
not-equal
not-equal
```

Answer (score 131, accepted):

There's no difference, `==` is a synonym for `=` (for the C/C++ people, I assume). See [here](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/comparison-ops.html), for example.

You could double-check just to be *really* sure or just for your interest by looking at the [bash source code](http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/bash/), should be somewhere in the parsing code there, but I couldn't find it straightaway.

Comment: There's no difference for *string* comparisons, but you can't use `=` for numeric comparisons in `(())` (you must use `==` in `(())` or `-eq` in `[]`, `test` or `[[]]`. See my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2600281/what-is-the-difference-between-operator-and-in-bash/2601583#2601583).

Comment: It's also worth noting that == was introduced in bash, but bourne shell does not support it.  In some systems, you'll notice that /bin/sh is actually bash, and in other systems, it's bourne.  I ran into that problem when a shell script worked correctly on multiple systems, but failed on one.  The == being unsupported in bourne was the reason it failed on the one.

Comment: Note, in ksh if you check the syntax, you get a depreciation warning with the single = syntax. `warning: line 3: '=' obsolete, use '=='`

Comment: There's no difference IN BASH. `==` does not work in all shells, hence not portable. Prefer `=`.

Comment: As @mak pointed out, == doesn't work in all shells, I confirmed that in Ubuntu 16.04 == doesn't work.