# Read line containing String (Bash)

Tags: string, bash, file, variables, contain

I have a file, and its something like this:

```
Device: name1
random text
Device: name2
random text
Device: name3
random text
```

I have a variable: MainComputer

What I want to get (for each name, i have like 40 names):

```
   MainComputer -> name1
   MainComputer -> name2
   MainComputer -> name3
```

What I have:

```
var="MainComputer"   
var1=$(awk '/Device/ {print $3}' file)
echo "$var -> $var1"
```

This only gives the arrow "->" and the link for the first variable, I want them for the other 40 variables...

Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Let me present you `awk`:

```
$ awk '/Device/ {print $2}' file
name1
name2
name3
```

This prints the second field on the lines containing `Device`. If you want to check that they start with Device, you can use `^Device:`.

#### Update

To get the output you mention in your edited question, use this:

```
$ awk -v var="MainComputer" '/Device/ {print var, "->", $2}' a
MainComputer -> name1
MainComputer -> name2
MainComputer -> name3
```

It provides the variable name through `-v` and then prints the line.

---

Find some comments regarding your script:

```
file="/scripts/file.txt"
while read -r line
do
     if [$variable="Device"]; then # where does $variable come from? also, if condition needs tuning
     device='echo "$line"' #to run a command you need `var=$(command)`
echo $device #this should be enough
fi
done <file.txt #why file.txt if you already stored it in $file?
```

Check [bash string equality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3265803/bash-string-equality) to see how `[[ "$variable" = "Device" ]]` should be the syntax (or similar).

Also, you could say `while read -r name value`, so that `$value` would contain from the 2nd value on.

Comment: Excuse me, forgot this:
variable="Device"

file="/scripts/file.txt"

while read -r line
do
     if [$variable="Device"]; then
     device='echo "$line"'
echo $device
fi
done <file.txt

Comment: fedorqui, that worked, ty!
But now when i have the output, how do i put them in a variable?

Comment: @Omnomnom just say `var=$(command)`. Or, in this case, `var=$(awk '/Device/ {print $2}' file)`.

Comment: @Omnomnom you just updated your question but what you say there is quite different from what you comment here. Try to clarify, please

Comment: Yes, thats what i had before with Cut, now there is no enter between the names, and they are shown on 1 line...

Comment: @Omnomnom Because to print them you need to quote the variable: `echo "$var"` will keep the format.

Comment: Yes I will, still got 1 problem though... If that is solved I can continue scripting!
And I know I'm new, but been using stackoverflow for a few years, just never posted something...
I've edited the question...

Comment: I'm gonna try this tomorrow but i'll think it will work, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Alternatively, let me present you grep and cut:

```
$ grep "^Device:" $file | cut "-d " -f2-
```

Comment: I guess `cut "-d " -f2-` is a typo. You may want to say `cut -d" "`

Comment: @fedorqui: How are they different? Both will be result to same argument value to `cut`. `-d" "` is just more readable to me. But from `bash` perspective, both are same. (That may not be the case for `cygwin`'s `cut.exe`, if being run from `cmd`. `cmd` passes `"` to child process.)

Comment: Exactly, you can just pick the version you like most.

Comment: You need to replace $file with the real path, or assign the file variable first.

Comment: @anishsane Weird, I hadn't seen `"-d "` before. It is a bit strange since it sets the parameter and its value all together. But it's also interesting, good to know!

Comment: @fedorqui: Yes, `"-d "` is unusual, but, as @anishsane points out, `-d" "` results in the _exact same string_ by the time `cut` sees it: both forms result in a single argument containing  `d` followed by a space, after the shell has performed _quote removal_.

Comment: @mklement0 fantastic, wasn't aware of it. To make it "persistent", I just posted it as an answer in [use space as a delimiter with cut command](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29798447/1983854).

Comment: Nicely done; if using _GNU_ `grep` is an option, a `grep` command alone will do: `grep -Po '^Device: \K.*' "$file"`. Quibble: please double-quote `$file`.