# How to do a logical OR operation for integer comparison in shell scripting?

Tags: bash, unix, if-statement, sh

I am trying to do a simple condition check, but it doesn't seem to work.

If `$#` is equal to `0` or is greater than `1` then say hello.

I have tried the following syntax with no success:

```
if [ "$#" == 0 -o "$#" > 1 ] ; then
 echo "hello"
fi

if [ "$#" == 0 ] || [ "$#" > 1 ] ; then
 echo "hello"
fi
```

Comment: They both work for me. Did you specify a shell in the *shebang* line?

Comment: @Jason I actually forgot the shebang line, but I tested it with it just now and it didn't work.

Comment: `>` is output redirection in sh/bash.  Now you probably have a file named `1`.

Comment: For information on Bash comparisons, please see my answers to previous questions [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2600281/what-is-the-difference-between-operator-and-in-bash/2601583#2601583) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3869072/test-for-non-zero-length-string-in-bash-n-var-or-var/3870055#3870055). For additional information regarding brackets, double brackets and double parentheses, see my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2188199/bash-double-or-single-bracket-parentheses-curly-braces/2188369#2188369).

Comment: It doesn't work cause you mistype the compraison: use "$#" == "0" or $# -eq 0

Answer (score 1031, accepted):

This should work:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ "$#" -eq 0 ] || [ "$#" -gt 1 ] ; then
    echo "hello"
fi
```

I'm not sure if this is different in other shells but if you wish to use <, >, you need to put them inside double parenthesis like so:

```
if (("$#" > 1))
 ...
```

Comment: I'm not sure if it's different in another shell but in bash, if you wish to use > or <, you have to put them in double parenthesis like so: (("$a" < "$b"))

Comment: @Doug: It's not that unix doesn't use them, it's that bash and all the other shells I know use them for input/output redirection.

Answer (score 58):

This code works for me:

```
#!/bin/sh

argc=$#
echo $argc
if [ $argc -eq 0 -o $argc -eq 1 ]; then
  echo "foo"
else
  echo "bar"
fi
```

I don't think sh supports "==". Use "=" to compare strings and -eq to compare ints.

```
man test
```

for more details.

Comment: What is the option for greater than? Where's the official documentation for tihs?

Comment: Should be `-gt` for greater than.  Or just replace it all with `[ $# -ne 1 ]`.

Comment: Greater than is -gt, see my answer. The official documentation is in man test as jbremnant has pointed out.

Comment: Just as an fyi for others, depending on your shell, most support == (now a days) as an comparison operator, however most of the time it is the same as the = operator. I would imagine that if you are using -gt and -ne for comparisons that it would be better practice to use -eq for == or = to keep your scripting style consistent. Happy Bashing :)

Answer (score 39):

If you are using the bash exit code status **$?** as variable, it's better to do this:

```
if [ $? -eq 4 -o $? -eq 8 ] ; then  
   echo "..."
fi
```

Because if you do:

```
if [ $? -eq 4 ] || [ $? -eq 8 ] ; then
```

The **left part of the OR** alters the **$?** variable, so the **right part of the OR** doesn't have the original **$?** value.

Comment: $# returns the number of arguments passed to the script. Useful for checking correct usage. It doesn't seem like the asker is using exit codes.

Answer (score 31):

Sometimes you need to use double brackets, otherwise you get an error like too many arguments

```
if [[ $OUTMERGE == *"fatal"* ]] || [[ $OUTMERGE == *"Aborting"* ]]
  then
fi
```

Comment: This is useful because it's the only thing here that I see showing an example of non-integer comparisons, which are slightly different in syntax.

Comment: Also, a space is required after "fatal"* . and "Aborting"*  before closing ]

Answer (score 14):

If a bash script

```
If [[ $input -gt number  ||  $input  -lt number  ]]
then 
    echo .........
else
    echo .........

fi

exit
```

Answer (score 8):

have you tried something like this:

```
if [ $# -eq 0 ] || [ $# -gt 1 ] 
then
 echo "$#"
fi
```

Comment: Yes, I have. It `echo`s hello even when I have a single argument.

Comment: The second `$#` might be the return value of the first test?

Answer (score 6):

From [Bash Reference Manual → 3.4.2 Special Parameters](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Special-Parameters)

> **#**
>   ($#) Expands to the number of positional parameters in decimal.

Therefore, `$#` will always be either 0 or a bigger integer.

So if you want to do something whenever `$#` is either 0 or bigger than 1, you just have to check if `$#` is or is not `1`:

```java
[ $# -eq 1 ] && echo "1 positional param" || echo "0 or more than 1"
```

This uses the syntax:

```
[ condition ] && {things if true} || {things if false}
```

Comment: in bash you can do something like: `[[ -n $A ]] && echo 1 || echo 2`

Comment: @premek.v thanks for the comment. My answer was very badly explained, I just edited it in the hope that it sheds more light to the topic.

Answer (score 1):

**And in Bash**

```
 line1=`tail -3 /opt/Scripts/wowzaDataSync.log | grep "AmazonHttpClient" | head -1`
 vpid=`ps -ef|  grep wowzaDataSync | grep -v grep  | awk '{print $2}'`
 echo "-------->"${line1}
    if [ -z $line1 ] && [ ! -z $vpid ]
    then
            echo `date --date "NOW" +%Y-%m-%d` `date --date "NOW" +%H:%M:%S` :: 
            "Process Is Working Fine"
    else
            echo `date --date "NOW" +%Y-%m-%d` `date --date "NOW" +%H:%M:%S` :: 
            "Prcess Hanging Due To Exception With PID :"${pid}
   fi
```

**OR in Bash**

```
line1=`tail -3 /opt/Scripts/wowzaDataSync.log | grep "AmazonHttpClient" | head -1`
vpid=`ps -ef|  grep wowzaDataSync | grep -v grep  | awk '{print $2}'`
echo "-------->"${line1}
   if [ -z $line1 ] || [ ! -z $vpid ]
    then
            echo `date --date "NOW" +%Y-%m-%d` `date --date "NOW" +%H:%M:%S` :: 
            "Process Is Working Fine"
    else
            echo `date --date "NOW" +%Y-%m-%d` `date --date "NOW" +%H:%M:%S` :: 
            "Prcess Hanging Due To Exception With PID :"${pid}
  fi
```