# using OR in shell script

Tags: shell

My shell script looks something like this...

```
if [[ $uptime -lt 0 ]];then
some code
fi

if [[ $questions -lt 1 ]];then
some code
fi

if [[ $slow -gt 10 ]];then
some code
fi
```

How do I use OR and have a single if clause?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to do a logical OR operation in Shell Scripting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4111475/how-to-do-a-logical-or-operation-in-shell-scripting)

Answer (score 67, accepted):

```
if [ $uptime -lt 0 -o $questions -lt 1 -o $slow -gt 10 ] ; then
    some code
fi
```

See `man test` for available syntax and options. The `[` operator is just shorthand for `test`, so the above code is equivalent to:

```
if test $uptime -lt 0 -o $questions -lt 1 -o $slow -gt 10 ; then
    some code
fi
```

Answer (score 74):

You should be able to use `||` or `-o` I think as follows:

```
if [ $uptime -lt 0 ] || [ $questions -lt 1 ] || [ $slow -gt 10 ]; then
    some code
fi
```

Comment: How is this less upvoted than `-o`? is there a drawback? it is insanely more readable

Comment: @Gulzar Most likely because of "I think" :)