# how to show "or" relationships in UNIX when writing a test statement?

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I have a problem writing a test statement.

If I want to write `[ $word = "t" (or) "I" ]`, meaning to test if the word is `T` or `t`
how should I write it?

Comment: Already answered on [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4111475/how-to-do-a-logical-or-operation-in-shell-scripting)

Comment: `[ $word = "t" -o $word = "T" ]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're using `#!/bin/sh` for Bash scripting, here is a great resource: http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_07_01.html

---

From `Table 7-2. Combining expressions` at the above link:

```
[ EXPR1 -a EXPR2 ]  True if both EXPR1 and EXPR2 are true.
[ EXPR1 -o EXPR2 ]  True if either EXPR1 or EXPR2 is true.
```

You want the second one, so that would become:

```
[ $word == "t" -o $word == "T" ]
```