# pip3 installs inside virtual environment with python3.6 failing due to ssl module not available

Tags: pip, python-venv, python-3.6

> **(py36venv) vagrant@pvagrant-dev-vm:/vagrant/venvs$ pip3 install pep8**
>
> *pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.*
>
> Collecting pep8   Could not fetch URL
>   https://pypi.python.org/simple/pep8/: There was a problem confirming
>   the ssl certificate: Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module
>   is not available. - skipping
>
> Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pep8 (from
>   versions: ) No matching distribution found for pep8

**Background information** - Trying to move to python 3.6.

Installed python3.6 using the below commands:

> wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.6.0/Python-3.6.0.tgz
>
> tar -xvf Python-3.6.0.tgz
>
> cd Python-3.6.0
>   ./configure --enable-optimizations
>   make -j8  sudo
>   make altinstall python3.6

Created virtualenv by:

> python3.6 -m venv py36venv
>
> source py36venv/bin/activate

Tried to install pep8

> (py36venv) pip3 install pep8
>
> pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl
>   module in Python is not available. 
>   Collecting pep8
>
> Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/pep8/: There was a problem
>   confirming the ssl certificate: Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the
>
> SSL module is not available. - skipping   Could not find a version
>   that satisfies the requirement pep8 (from versions: ) No matching
>   distribution found for pep8

Comment: Do you have `libssl-dev` installed, does the Makefile point to the right ssl, is it enabled in the makefile? Also see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5937337/building-python-with-ssl-support-in-non-standard-location

Comment: Uncommented the following - **SSL=/usr/local/ssl
_ssl _ssl.c \
    -DUSE_SSL -I$(SSL)/include -I$(SSL)/include/openssl \
    -L$(SSL)/lib -lssl -lcrypto  **

Comment: If you figured out a solution feel free to answer your own question.

Answer (score 58):

I followed the below steps for python3.6 installation in ubuntu 14.04 and virtualenv pip installs works fine.

**Python 3.6 Installation:**

```
sudo apt-get install python3-dev libffi-dev libssl-dev
wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.6.0/Python-3.6.0.tgz  
tar xvf Python-3.6.0.tgz
cd Python-3.6.0
./configure --enable-optimizations  
make -j8  
sudo make altinstall
python3.6
```

If seeing the following error --

> zipimport.ZipImportError: can't decompress data; zlib not available
>   make: *** [altinstall] Error 1

try:

```
sudo apt-get install zlib1g-dev
```

**Validation:**

Create virtualenv in python3.6:

```
python3.6 -m venv testenv
source testenv/bin/activate
pip install pep8
```

using pip:

```
(testenv) vagrant@pvagrant-dev-vm:~$ pip install pep8
*Collecting pep8
  Downloading pep8-1.7.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (41kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 51kB 4.1MB/s
Installing collected packages: pep8
Successfully installed pep8-1.7.0*

(testenv) vagrant@pvagrant-dev-vm:~$ pip list

pep8 (1.7.0) 
pip (9.0.1)
setuptools (28.8.0)
```

Comment: What does `-j8` in `make -j8` do?

Comment: -j [jobs], --jobs[=jobs]
            Specifies  the  number  of jobs (commands) to run simultaneously.  If there is more
            than one -j option, the last one is effective.  If the -j option is  given  without
            an argument, make will not limit the number of jobs that can run simultaneously. Hope its helpful, for more information, please refer man pages on make

Comment: Note: It takes quite a long time to compile and install (depending on your system of course).  It took ~20 minutes for me, running an AMD FX(tm)-9590 Eight-Core Processor, but it worked.

Comment: Are you saying that if you compile with `libssl-dev` absent, that you need to reinstall?

Comment: @surfer190 Correct you are!  I forgot to install `libssl-dev` and ran into the error described in the OP.  After install `libssl-dev`, re-compiling, and re-installing, `pip` works without issue.

Comment: Is libffi-dev actually needed?  I seem to have built and installed without it.

Answer (score 14):

I stumbled upon the same issue when I tried to create a virtual environment utilising python3.6.0. Here is my solution for Mac OS X 10.12.2 (Py_minion comment was pretty close):

## Setup

I created the environment by the following steps:
downloading python3.6.0
running

```
./configure --prefix=<some_path>`
make
make install
mkvirtualenv --python=<some_path/bin/python3.6> foo
```

So basically similar to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11301911/1286093

An indication if you have the same issue as I had would be a similar line when running `make`

```
The necessary bits to build these optional modules were not found: _ssl
```

## Solution

### Install openssl

```
brew install openssl
brew unlink openssl && brew link openssl --force
```

### Change Module/Setup or Module/Setup.dist

You can find those files in the directory of the downloaded Python version.

Comment in and, if necessary change, lines 209 - 211 (I had to change the SSL variable to my openssl location).

```
SSL=/usr/local/opt/openssl <---- THIS DEPENDS ON YOUR INSTALLATION
_ssl _ssl.c \
    -DUSE_SSL -I$(SSL)/include -I$(SSL)/include/openssl \
    -L$(SSL)/lib -lssl -lcrypto
```

Given that this was the location of openssl

### Set environment variables

```
export CFLAGS="-I$(brew --prefix openssl)/include"
export LDFLAGS="-L$(brew --prefix openssl)/lib"
```

### make and install again

Running

```
./configure --prefix=<some_path>`
make
make install
mkvirtualenv --python=<some_path/bin/python3.6> foo
```

again did the trick for me

Comment: For those that don't have sudo and brew: openssl can be acquired from https://www.openssl.org/

Answer (score 8):

Running make reported to me in the shell output:

```
The necessary bits to build these optional modules were not found:
_bz2                  _dbm                  _gdbm              
_sqlite3              _ssl                  _tkinter           
To find the necessary bits, look in setup.py in detect_modules() for the module's name.
```

**What solved the problem** in my case (Linux Mint 18.1, openssl already installed) **was editing the setup.py** in the Python-3.6.0 folder **adding there** the path to where the openssl installation put the ssl.h file on my system into ( /usr/include/openssl/ssl.h ). Here the section in which I have added the line **'/usr/include'**:

```
    # Detect SSL support for the socket module (via _ssl)
    search_for_ssl_incs_in = [
                          '/usr/local/ssl/include/',
                          '/usr/contrib/ssl/include/',
                          '/usr/include/'
                         ]
    ssl_incs = find_file('openssl/ssl.h', inc_dirs,
                         search_for_ssl_incs_in
                         )
```

Comment: So happy I found your answer, it fixed this issue for me (Ubuntu 16.04)

Comment: This works on my Ubuntu 16.04. Should be the most upvoted answer.

Answer (score 7):

I have solved this problem on Ubuntu-16.04.1.
First you need to install necessary libraries. To install open Terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>), then type;

```
 sudo apt-get install build-essential checkinstall
 sudo apt-get install libreadline-gplv2-dev libncursesw5-dev libssl-dev libsqlite3-dev tk-dev libgdbm-dev libc6-dev libbz2-dev
```

After that go the directory where your python file is then reconfigure and reinstall python3.6 .

```
 cd /opt/Python3.6/
./configure
 make 
sudo make install
```

**NOTE**
If you installed Python3.6 via ppa, then reinstall it again;

```
sudo apt-get install python3.6
```

Now you should be able to use *pip3.6*

Comment: Worked like a charm on debian (I installed python3.6 from source). Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

I ran into the same error when building Python 3.6.1 from source under CentOS 7.
For CentOS7, I had to first:

```
sudo yum install openssl-dev
```

Then:

```
./configure --enable-optimizations
make altinstall
```

Now `pip3.6` works :-)

Comment: Same configuration :)

Comment: WORKS, but for RHEL 7.3 it's `sudo yum install openssl-devel`

Answer (score 1):

> A complete script can be found [HERE](https://gist.github.com/jerodg/f66257934158a6292dea840e15b3adb2)

## Install Prerequisites

**For RHEL/CentOS**

`sudo yum -y install gcc gcc-c++ zlib zlib-devel libffi-devel openssl-devel wget`

**For Ubuntu/Debian**

`sudo apt-get -y install build-essential python-dev python-setuptools python-pip 
python-smbus libncursesw5-dev libgdbm-dev libc6-dev zlib1g-dev libsqlite3-dev 
tk-dev libssl-dev openssl libffi-dev wget`

## Download Python

> Modify for the version of python you want
>
> [Python Versions](https://www.python.org/ftp/python/)

`cd /var/tmp
sudo wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.x.x/Python-x.x.x.tgz
sudo tar xf Python-3.*.tgz
cd Python-3*`

## Configure/Make/Install

`sudo ./configure --enable-optimizations --enable-shared --prefix=/usr/local
sudo make && make altinstall`

## Cleanup Shared Library & Add to Path

Stripping the shared library of debugging symbols can speed up execution when running parallel scripts.

`sudo make && make altinstall
sudo strip /usr/local/lib/libpython3.7m.so.1.0
sudo echo 'export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}:/usr/local/lib' >> /etc/profile.d/python.sh
sudo echo 'export PATH=${PATH}:~/usr/local/bin/' >> /etc/profile.d/python.sh
sudo echo '/usr/local/lib' >> /etc/ld.so.conf
sudo ldconfig`

### Reference

- [Gist](https://gist.github.com/jerodg/f66257934158a6292dea840e15b3adb2)
- [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4111475/4434405)
- [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27022373/python3-importerror-no-module-named-ctypes-when-using-value-from-module-mul)
- [Daniel Erikson](https://danieleriksson.net/2017/02/08/how-to-install-latest-python-on-centos)
- [Unix StackExchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/303983/258174)
- [TLDP](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_07_02.html)