# Can't pip install packages in python 3.6 due to ssl error

Tags: python, ssl

I'm working on a remote server. When I try to install anything with pip within my virtual environment I get an error:

```
(venv) [barta@bivoj program]$ pip install -r requirements.txt 
pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
Collecting joblib==0.11 (from -r requirements.txt (line 1))
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/joblib/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available. - skipping
```

Everything is working fine with python 2.7. Can I solve this problem by myself (I don't have root access) or do I need to contact the administrator?

First I had this problem when I installed python 3.6 in my home folder. I figured that the problem might be because it's in my home folder, so I asked for a clean install of python 3.6.

I considered changing the setup.py and install again in my home, as suggested here by Claudio:

[pip3 installs inside virtual environment with python3.6 failing due to ssl module not available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41489439/pip3-installs-inside-virtual-environment-with-python3-6-failing-due-to-ssl-modul)

but I didn't find any openssl folder. There is openssl in /usr/bin, but that is not a directory. I searched for the ssl.h file, but did not find it anywhere.

Comment: You can try to build a local python 3 with a local openssl. Or just ask the admin to install a packaged python 3 for you.

Answer (score 10):

Sounds like you've built python from source without `libssl-dev` present.

Run:

```
sudo apt-get install libssl-dev
sudo ./configure
sudo make altinstall
```

Comment: That's going to be difficult without root access.

Comment: Oh, sorry, skipped that part in the question, I'll update the answer

Comment: @pvg Updated. (Take a look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/5939170/723891)

Comment: I'm not the person asking, although the question is about python 3, they appear to have a working python 2 with SSL as it is. Sanest thing is really to just get a hold of someone with privileges and have them install python 3 with the package manager.

Answer (score 3):

Tested in Ubuntu 16.04/18.04

In Python-3.6.4/Modules/Setup uncomment the following lines:

```
#   SSL=/usr/local/ssl
#   _ssl _ssl.c \
#       -DUSE_SSL -I$(SSL)/include -I$(SSL)/include/openssl \
#       -L$(SSL)/lib -lssl -lcrypto
```

Then recompile the package:

```
$ sudo ./configure --enable-optimizations
$ sudo make altinstall
```

Also make sure that `libssl-dev` is installed (this is the package for debian, anyway).

This also works for Python-3.7.x.

Comment: Unfortunately this did not work for me.
sudo make altinstall
gives the following error.

/usr/src/Python-3.7.0/./Modules/_ssl.c:3674: undefined reference to `SSL_CTX_get_default_passwd_cb'
/usr/src/Python-3.7.0/./Modules/_ssl.c:3675: undefined reference to `SSL_CTX_get_default_passwd_cb_userdata'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [python] Error 1

Answer (score 2):

This is how I did:

```
sudo apt-get install libssl-dev
wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.6.5/Python-3.6.5.tgz
tar -xvf Python-3.6.5.tgz
cd Python-3.6.5/

./configure
sudo make
sudo make install
```

Comment: Literally spent 45 minutes for this and installed on my Ec2. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I got same error but actually I created **python environment** using a latest version of **python2.7.13** and this python version was installed via [source](http://https//www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.13/Python-2.7.13.tgz):

```
./configure --prefix /usr/bin/python2.7.13
make altinstall
```

Then creating **virtualenv**:

```
virtualenv --python=/usr/bin/python2.7.13/bin/python2.7 py2.7.13env
```

After spending a lot of time I found that one library named `libreadline6-dev` was missing. So installed it:

```
sudo apt-get install libreadline6-dev
```

and repeated **compile** and **make install** steps as mentioned above and again created the virtual env. Everything worked fine this time!

Answer (score 0):

If this is Windows, you need to install OpenSSL
https://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html