# Jupyter missing _sqlite3 and pysqlite2

Tags: linux, python-3.x, sqlite, jupyter-notebook, pysqlite

trying to get jupyter (ipython3) running on Python3.5, I installed it using

```
sudo pip3 install jupyter
```

However, when trying to launch jupyter notebook I receive the error that the modules _sqlite3 and pysqlite2 are missing. I tried installing them via pip3. For pysqlite2 there seems to be no version availabel (?). For sqlite3 I get

> RuntimeError: Package 'sqlite3' must not be downloaded from pypi

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/notebook/services/sessions/sessionmanager.py", line 10, in <module>
    import sqlite3   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/sqlite3/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from sqlite3.dbapi2 import *   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/sqlite3/dbapi2.py", line 27, in <module>
    from _sqlite3 import * ImportError: No module named '_sqlite3'
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/jupyter-notebook", line 7, in <module>
    from notebook.notebookapp import main
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 79, in <module>
    from .services.sessions.sessionmanager import SessionManager
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/notebook/services/sessions/sessionmanager.py", line 13, in <module>
    from pysqlite2 import dbapi2 as sqlite3
ImportError: No module named 'pysqlite2'
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I was missing `libsqlite3-dev` when building Python3.
So after running `sudo apt-get install libsqlite3-dev` and rebuilding Python3 everything seems to work now.

Comment: Worked for me. Installed the appropriate package (for Fedora) and compiled [as instructed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41489439/pip3-installs-inside-virtual-environment-with-python3-6-failing-due-to-ssl-modul).

Answer (score 8):

I am on Centos 7 and built Python3.8 from source. Indeed as Suppenkasper said I needed to first `sudo yum install libsqlite3x-devel.x86_64` before rebuilding Python3.8 using `sudo make altinstall`.

You can find the exact sqlite package name through `yum list | grep sqlite`.

Comment: This is the only right solution for CentOS. Works for py3.9 too

Answer (score 3):

I got the same error in jupyter notebook.
I have installed python 3.7.2 from source in my `tmp` folder in
`Ubuntu 16.04.7 LTS (Xenial Xerus)`.
It was missing libsqlite3-dev
So first install `libsqlite3-dev` using

```
$ sudo apt-get install libsqlite3-dev
```

Then rebuild your python 3.7.2, to do this
go to your python installed folder in my case `/tmp/python-3.7.2` and run

```
$ cd /tmp/Python-3.7.2
$ ./configure --enable-optimizations
$ sudo make altinstall
```

Comment: is this still a requirement for using jupytr and/or does it have to be installed before python still?

Answer (score 0):

I have to reinstall the python and it works again.