# SSL error after brew install python3

Tags: python, ssl, homebrew

I just installed python using:
    brew install python3

I then ran 
    pip3 install virtualenv

I got this error:
   pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
Collecting virtualenv
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/virtualenv/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available. - skipping
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement virtualenv (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for virtualenv

How do I fix the SSL error?

Comment: You sure you're running the pip3 that came with your brew-installed python3? Check the location of pip3, python3, etc.

Comment: Please see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41489439/pip3-installs-inside-virtual-environment-with-python3-6-failing-due-to-ssl-modul/42798679

Comment: @pvg I checked python3 is here:
sys.path = [
    '/Users/bootadmin',
    '/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python36.zip',
    '/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6',
    '/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload',
    '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages',
    '/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages',
]
I wasn't sure how to find the pip3 directory

Comment: @alexisdevarennes I looked at that and didn't find a solution because I am trying to use homebrew to install python.  Should I not do that?

Answer (score 2):

Seems brew skipped the certifi step.

Copied from my local installation, this runs the certifi ssl install step.

```
brew install openssl
ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/openssl/{version}/include/openssl /usr/bin/openssl
pip install certifi
```

Then run this:

```
# install_certifi.py
#
# sample script to install or update a set of default Root Certificates
# for the ssl module.  Uses the certificates provided by the certifi package:
#       https://pypi.python.org/pypi/certifi

import os
import os.path
import ssl
import stat
import subprocess
import sys

STAT_0o775 = ( stat.S_IRUSR | stat.S_IWUSR | stat.S_IXUSR
             | stat.S_IRGRP | stat.S_IWGRP | stat.S_IXGRP
             | stat.S_IROTH |                stat.S_IXOTH )


def main():
    openssl_dir, openssl_cafile = os.path.split(
        ssl.get_default_verify_paths().openssl_cafile)

    print(" -- pip install --upgrade certifi")
    subprocess.check_call([sys.executable,
        "-E", "-s", "-m", "pip", "install", "--upgrade", "certifi"])

    import certifi

    # change working directory to the default SSL directory
    os.chdir(openssl_dir)
    relpath_to_certifi_cafile = os.path.relpath(certifi.where())
    print(" -- removing any existing file or link")
    try:
        os.remove(openssl_cafile)
    except FileNotFoundError:
        pass
    print(" -- creating symlink to certifi certificate bundle")
    os.symlink(relpath_to_certifi_cafile, openssl_cafile)
    print(" -- setting permissions")
    os.chmod(openssl_cafile, STAT_0o775)
    print(" -- update complete")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: I ran that code and got this error:
f:programming bootadmin$ python3 test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 9, in <module>
    import ssl
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 101, in <module>
    import _ssl             # if we can't import it, let the error propagate
ImportError: dlopen(/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload/_ssl.cpython-36m-darwin.so, 2): Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib

Comment: Which error? did you run pip install certifi and brew install openssl?

Comment: Yup run brew install openssl :)

Comment: @alexidevarennes   I tried those.  pip install certifi seemed to work but failed for the python2.  I  ran into this error with brew install openssl:
Warning: Refusing to link: openssl
Linking keg-only openssl means you may end up linking against the insecure,
deprecated system OpenSSL while using the headers from Homebrew's openssl.
Instead, pass the full include/library paths to your compiler e.g.:
  -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib

Comment: Run:  brew link --force openssl OR add export PATH=$(brew --prefix openssl)/bin:$PATH in ~/.bash_profile OR ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/openssl/{version}/include/openssl /usr/bin/openssl

Comment: brew link --force openssl  gave the same - refusing to link error
how do I do this one? add export PATH=$(brew --prefix openssl)/bin:$PATH in ~/.bash_profile
for the ln -s, I got ln: /usr/bin/openssl: Operation not permitted