# Bash programming with conditional statment problem

Tags: bash

the code here is to get the user input 
if 1, cp something
if 2 cp another thing
the problem here is that it told me the command is not find in line 7

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Add News or Phinishing attacks:"
echo "1. Add News"
echo "2. Add Phinishing attacks"
read -e type
if [ "$type" == "1" ]; then
    cp /var/www/html/INFOSEC/english/news/newsletters.html /var/www/html/INFOSEC/english/news/test.html
    cp /var/www/html/INFOSEC/english/whatsnew/whatsnew.html /var/www/html/INFOSEC/english/whatsnew/test.html
elif [ "$type" == "2" ] ; then
    cp /var/www/html/INFOSEC/english/news1/newsletters2.html /var/www/html/INFOSEC/english/news1/test.html
fi
```

Also, can i directly compare the user input with value such as 1 or 2 ???
Please take a look thanks .

Comment: alright seems to be space problem. the bash programming is not that friendly

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
read x 
if [[ $x = 1 ]]; then
    echo 1
elif [[ $x = 2 ]]; then
    echo 2;
fi
```

Comment: The `[` command is the old venerable test built-in, while the `[[`, the extended test command, was introduced in Bash 2.02 and can do a lot more.  For example, you can use `&&`, `||`, `<`, and `>` within `[[` and `]]` test, but not within `[` and `]`.  You can find more details here: http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/testconstructs.html.  (FWIW I always use `[[`; maybe others can comment on the need for `[` ?).

Comment: @Ray:  Why don't you use == instead of = ?  That is, if you are a C programmer.

Comment: Heh, good observation, grok12.  That code is a funny mix of choices; `-eq` or `==` might have looked more normal there.  Of interest: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2600281/what-is-the-difference-between-operator-and-in-bash/2601583#2601583.