# Is there a difference between "=" and "==" in Bash?

Tags: bash

As far as I can see, in most shell versions the expressions

```
if [ x = y ]
```

and

```
if [ x == y ]
```

have the same meaning.

Also, I saw, that there are versions, that don't allow `==`, only `=`.

So is it true, that I can always use `=` instead of `==`?

Comment: You can always use a single `=` with the `test` (aka `[`) command.  The double `==` does not work in all shells.

Comment: @fedorqui view [Elliott Frisch answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20449568/4767343)

Comment: Since you say you've already discovered some differences yourself, it might help if you name them so people answering know where to start.

Comment: http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/comparison-ops.html

Comment: @JoseRicardoBustosM. the fact that an answer points out the difference doesn't mean the question is duplicate. There, they ask about `==` and `-eq`, here `==` and `=`. Found an exact duplicate: [What is the difference between operator “=” and “==” in Bash?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2600281/1983854)

Comment: By the way, for these kind of cases I use http://symbolhound.com/, where you can indicate, for example, a query like "bash = ==" which google doesn't recognise.

Comment: @fedorqui thanks, I did not know about [symbolhound.com](http://symbolhound.com/) ....