# Error in sh script, if statement gives unexpected end of file

Tags: linux, if-statement, syntax-error

I am not so familiar with Linux and shell script, anyhow I tried out some command that I want to add to my start script but ran in to some problems.

I have tried in different ways to get rid of the

```
: unexpected end of file"
```

and

```
 command not found
```

in this

```
#!/bin/bash
DEBUG="$1"
if [ "$DEBUG" = "debug" ]; then
echo "Lets start in debug mode"
fi
```

And I trie to run it from command line ike this

```
# sh myscript.sh debug
```

Have also  tried to alter the if like this

```
if [ "$DEBUG" = "debug" ]
 then
  echo ......
```

but the error remains
I know I can run it like this but it does not metter it seems

```
 ./myscript.sh debug
```

A hint or tip is most appreciated !!  :)

Comment: Which text editor are you using? Can you show the output of `cat -A script.sh`? It is more likely you have DOS style endings from a Windows text editor

Comment: You are right @Inian , I used Winscp in widows and moved it to my Wirtual Box originaly. After moving it I used VI in Linux to edit the file. Solution for me was to use as you said "dos2unix"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert your script using `dos2unix`. The script in question does *not* have any violations in script that could cause the error reported.

The error is likely because of the CRLF endings copied from a Windows machine/Text editor and running under a Linux/Unix machine. Convert the End of Line (EOL) sequence `\r\n` to just `\n` by running

```
dos2unix script.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

Be careful about white space, for example this work for me ( with double equal )  :

```
#!/bin/bash
DEBUG="$1"
if [ "$DEBUG" == "debug" ]; then 
   echo "Lets start in debug mode"
else
  echo "try again"
fi
```

You can remove else statement

Comment: This shouldn't be a problem. Using `=` is absolutely fine. OP likely has carriage return characters which is causing these errors

Comment: Yes it will work, also try original code from the author. That will also work

Comment: `==` is a `bash` extension, `=` is standard.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2600281/what-is-the-difference-between-operator-and-in-bash

Comment: But it's a bash file

Comment: But bash implements the standard operator.