# Sorting not working correctly in bash

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed, grep

I have a variable `VarExp` with following 2 values

```
1.5.2
1.5.3
```

I have another variable `VarCurr` with following 1 value

```
1.8.1
```

I want to compare `VarCurr` with `VarExp` and want to `echo SUCCESS` only when

```
VarCurr >= VarExp
```

I have written the following code but it it always returning `FAILURE`

```
VarExp='1.5.2 1.5.3'
VarCurr='1.8.1'

printf -v versions '%s\n%s' "$VarExp" "$VarCurr"
if [[ $versions = "$(sort -V <<< "$versions")" ]]; then
    echo 'FAILURE'
else
    echo 'SUCCESS'
fi
```

`VarCurr` need to be >= the lowest value contained in `VarExp`

Comment: I noticed you're using the assignment instead of equality operator. And are you sure you don't want success when the condition is satisfied?

Comment: Ofcourse, I want `'SUCCESS'` when the condition is satisfied.

Comment: @argx `=` is the equality operator in `bash`. There are no assignments in conditional expressions.

Comment: @Barmar Great info, my mistake. There's a [SO question about it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2600281/what-is-the-difference-between-operator-and-in-bash) too. Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: I think you have success and failure backwards. `$VarCurr` is higher than `$VarExp`, so it sorts after it, and that's the order you have in `$versions`. So when it's equal to the sorted result, it should be `SUCCESS`,not `FAILURE.

Comment: Also, what should the result be if `VarCurr` is *between* multiple values contained in `VarExp`? Or does `VarCurr` need to be >= the highest value contained in `VarExp`?

Comment: This doesn't compare it to each of the values in `$VarExp`, it just compares to the first one, because `sort` sorts lines.

Comment: `VarCurr` need to be >= the lowest value contained in `VarExp`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With GNU sort for `-V`:

```
$ cat tst.sh
#!/bin/bash
varExp='1.5.2 1.5.3'
varCurr=$1

minVarExp=$(printf '%s\n' $varExp | sort -V | head -1)
maxOfVers=$(printf '%s\n' "$minVarExp" "$varCurr" | sort -V | tail -1)

if [[ $maxOfVers = $varCurr ]]; then
    echo 'SUCCESS'
else
    echo 'FAILURE'
fi

$ ./tst.sh 1.8.1
SUCCESS

$ ./tst.sh 1.5.1
FAILURE

$ ./tst.sh 1.5.2
SUCCESS
```

Answer (score 4):

I recommend using a language that can properly objectify version objects and can understand major.minor.build.revision.  Here's an example bash script which borrows from Perl for version parsing:

```
#!/bin/bash

VarExp='1.5.2 1.5.3'
VarCurr='1.8.1'

for i in $VarExp; do {
    perl -e 'use version;exit !(version->parse('$VarCurr') >= version->parse('$i'));' && {
        echo 'SUCCESS'
        exit
    }
}; done

echo 'FAILURE'
exit
```

Of course it might be more graceful just to write the whole thing in Perl.

Edit: Here's another example using Python:

```
#!/bin/bash

VarExp='1.5.3 1.5.6'
VarCurr='1.5.3'

for i in $VarExp; do {
    python -c 'from distutils.version import LooseVersion;\
    exit(LooseVersion("'$VarCurr'") >= LooseVersion("'$i'"))' || {
        echo 'SUCCESS'
        exit
    }
}; done

echo 'FAILURE'
exit
```

Comment: I am getting output as `FAILURE` It should be `SUCCESS`  I am using values `VarCurr='1.5.3'` and `VarExp='1.5.3 1.5.6'`

Comment: @meallhour Odd.  It's working as expected with those values for me.  Were those variables the only code you changed?

Comment: When I do `echo $VarCurr` I get `1.5.3` Similarly, when I do `echo $VarExp` I get `1.5.3 1.5.6`  With these values I am still getting `FAILURE`

Comment: `VarCurr` need to be >= the lowest value contained in `VarExp`

Comment: @meallhour Only thing I can figure is that maybe your installation of Perl doesn't include the version module.  What happens if you `perl -e 'use version; print version->parse(1.5.3)'` from the console?  For me it outputs `v1.5.3`.

Comment: I am getting `v1.5.3` as well

Comment: do you think i might have trailing or beginning spaces in `VarCurr` and `VarExp`? this is because i am calculating values for `VarCurr` and `VarExp` using few other commands

Comment: @meallhour I don't think that matters.  I just tried inserting a space in VarCurr but Perl objectified the value the same.  Hey, I just added a Python alternative.  See whether you have better luck with that one.

Comment: I am getting output as `FAILURE` even using python

Comment: I hope you understand that `VarExp='1.5.3 1.5.6'` has 2 different versions separated by space

Comment: @meallhour Maybe there's something weird with how the bash interpreter is tokenizing the values in $VarExp.  Within the for loop, try inserting `echo "i = $i"` and see whether the values expected are the values passed.

Comment: I have restarted server after which it is working fine. Thanks for your help!!

Comment: please suggest if it is okay to use `return 1` instead of `exit` because i want to wrap this logic in a function and need to execute few more statements after the function call

Comment: @meathour You should `return 0` on success or `1` on failure.  Then you can `functionname && success || fail` using conditional execution.  Google "bash function return values" for a flood of examples.  If you get stuck, create a new question post.  I'm headed to bed for now.  Best of luck!

Answer (score 3):

If you're using bash, you can use arrays. They make dealing with lists so much easier and safer. In addition, since you can't rely on feature availability like `sort -V` to be portable, one option might be to convert your numbers to something that works better with bash comparisons. The following assumes that no numbers in your strings will be greater than 3 digits. Salt to taste.

```
#!/bin/bash

VarExp='1.5.2 1.5.3'
VarCurr='1.8.1'

a=( $VarExp )

function padsemver {
    local IFS=.
    local -a a=()
    read -a a <<<"$1"
    printf '%03d' "${a[@]}"
}

x="$(padsemver "$VarCurr")"

for i in "${a[@]}"; do
    if [[ 10#"$x" -gt 10#"$(padsemver $i)" ]]; then
        printf '%s\n' "SUCCESS"
        exit 0
    fi
done

printf '%s\n' "FAILURE"
exit 1
```

This uses the `padsemver()` function to convert, say, `1.5.3` into `001005003`, which makes it compatible with a numeric comparison in `test` or `[[`.  (The `10#` makes sure that a number starting with a 0 will be interpreted as decimal rather than octal.)

You could of course put the whole test into its own function rather than a stand-alone script if that was what you needed.

Answer (score 2):

Could you please try following and let me know if this helps you.

```
varExp="1.5.2
1.5.4"
VarCurr="1.8.1"
echo "$varExp" |
awk -v current="$VarCurr" '{
  curr=current
  value=$0
  gsub(/\./,"",curr)
  gsub(/\./,"",value)
  if(curr>=value){
    print "SUCCESS, value of varExp " current " is more than variable varExp " $0"."
  }
}'
```

Output will be as follows.

```
SUCCESS, value of varExp 1.8.1 is more than variable varExp 1.5.2.
SUCCESS, value of varExp 1.8.1 is more than variable varExp 1.5.4.
```

Assuming that your variable named `varExp` has numeric values in new lines so by wrapping its value in `"` will keep the new lines alive in it.

Comment: Stripping the dots won't always work.  What happens when the minor revision reaches 10?  1.10.0 > 1.5.2, but awk will perform a string comparison of 1100 and 152, assigning a higher value to 152.  At least that's how it behaves in gawk on my system.  At any rate, there will be some ambiguity.  1.08.1 should sort higher than 1.5.2, but it won't as your code is written.