# Difference between = and == in bash double brackets [[ ]]

Tags: linux, string, bash

I've read on many places that the correct way to do string comparison in double brackets is by using the double equality operator, ==

But I found that I've instead been using the single equality operator, =

Honestly I'm a bit worried that my code might be doing something unexpected that I'm not seeing, however I wasn't able to verify that it's doing something wrong nor find any conclusive documentation on the subject

```
[[ "testo" = "t"* ]] && echo true
true
[[ "testo" == "t"* ]] && echo true
true
```

And it doesn't seem to be doing an assignment

```
[[ $t = "b" ]]; echo $t
(nothing)
```

Can someone maybe shed some light on the subject

Comment: `=` is the **standardized** string comparison operator for `[`/`test`; having support for using `==` for string comparisons at all is a nonstandard extension (though `[[` is _also_ a nonstandard extension, the latter has useful properties, whereas `==` has no value beyond letting folks be lazy and use syntax from other languages).

Comment: So everything you read saying `==` was correct is full-stop wrong, untrustworthy, not-to-be-used. See https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html for the relevant standard -- while `[[` is itself nonstandard and will always support `==`, being in the habit of using `=` will make your code more compatible when you're writing for POSIX shells and using `[` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, yikes, can't trust the internet tbh, I'll definitely read through the entire specification.
I did get into the habit of writing =  because I've been trying to write more POSIX compatible scripts, using [ / test instead of [[ where it doesn't make a difference in the simplicity of my code.
Stack overflow also associated my question already and there is also an answer there... smh
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2600281/what-is-the-difference-between-operator-and-in-bash

Comment: BTW, the POSIXy way to write the expression overall would be to use a `case`, as in: `case $t in t*) echo "true";; esac`

Comment: Nice, I'll take note